# Need help with sed command

Tags: sed, command

I need help entering a single `sed` command to search for games released between the years 2000 and 2009 (inclusive) in the below. I've tried the (/) search but it did not work for me.

```
1   Wii Sports                    Wii  2006 Nintendo            41.36
2   Super Mario Bros.             NES  1985 Nintendo            29.08
3   Duck Hunt                     NES  1985 Nintendo            26.93
4   Tetris                        GB   1989 Nintendo            23.20
5   Mario Kart Wii                Wii  2008 Nintendo            15.91
6   Wii Sports Resort             Wii  2009 Nintendo            15.61
7   Kinect Adventures!            X360 2010 MS Game Studios     15.09
8   New Super Mario Bros. Wii     Wii  2009 Nintendo            14.53
9   Wii Play                      Wii  2007 Nintendo            13.96
10  Super Mario World             SNES 1991 Nintendo            12.78
11  New Super Mario Bros.         DS   2006 Nintendo            11.28
12  Pokémon Red/Green/Blue        GB   1998 Nintendo            11.27
13  Super Mario Land              GB   1989 Nintendo            10.83
14  Call of Duty: Black Ops       X360 2010 Activision           9.76
15  Mario Kart DS                 DS   2005 Nintendo             9.71
16  Super Mario Bros. 3           NES  1990 Nintendo             9.54
17  Grand Theft Auto:San Andreas  PS2  2004 Rockstar Games       9.43
18  Call of Duty: Modern Warfare  X360 2011 Activision           9.07
19  Grand Theft Auto V            X360 2013 Rockstar Games       9.06
```

Comment: what does this mean? ... `it did not work for me`

Answer (score 5):

Better to use **awk** for this use case as text processing tool , In the meantime you can use the above to search what you are looking for ( note that this will work only with your list ):

```
sed  -n '/200[0-9]/p' file
```

> -n : will suppress the complete file output
>
> p command : is used to print the matching pattern

With **AWK** ( supposing the columns are separated by tab ) :

```
awk -F '\t' '{if($4 >= 2000 && $4 <= 2009 ) {print $0}}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

If those are fixed-width fields and all the characters have a width of one and only one (no zero width nor double-width characters and no control character such as TAB), you could do:

```
<your-file grep -E '^.{38}200[0-9] '
```

Assuming the year field starts at column 39.

That is, look for lines that start (`^`) with `38` characters (`.`) followed by 200 followed by a character in the 0 to 9 range, followed by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sed, I recommend using grep.

Run in terminal: cat YOURFILE | grep YEAR

Replace YOURFILE with the name of your file. Replace YEAR with the year you want to see all the games that were released in that year.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can you `grep` for something between year X and Y ?